# Can we use .filter() function with conditional rules for the searched properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, filter

Let's assume that we have the following .filter function:

```js
search(searchQuery: string) {
  let results = myArray.filter(item => 
    item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) ||
    item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
  );

  return results;
}
```

For this example we can consider that `item` doesn't have a `description` property always but only some times.
In this case function will fail with an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

How can we can still search in the array and include the `description` property in the search only if it exists? Is this possible within the `.filter()` function?

Comment: How about  `(item.title && item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)) ||
    (item.description && item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a default value.

Either directly

```
(item.description || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
```

or take a destructuring with a default values.

```
results = myArray.filter(({ title = '', description = '' }) => 
    title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) ||
    description.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        title: 'Test 123',
    },
    {
        title: 'Test 123',
        description: 'test',
    },
    {
        title: 'What',
    },
    {
        title: 'Fix',
        description: '456123',
    },
];

const search = (text) => {
    let results = myArray.filter(item => {
        if (item.description) {
            return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(text) || item.description.toLowerCase().includes(text);
        }
    });
  
    return results;
}

const results = search('test');

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search(searchQuery: string) {
  return myarray.filter(item => 'description' in item
    ? item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
    : item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
  );
}
```

Might want to do the same check for `title` too but how far down do you go.